# How can I export contacts & SMS from broken Galaxy S3 and import them onto Google Nexus 6P?

Tags: samsung, google, samsung-kies

I've got myself in a pickle. The screen AND buttons on my Galaxy S3 have broken, so I've acquired a Nexus 6P phone. My old contacts and SMS messages are stored on the Galaxy S3 phone itself. I am able to plug the phone into the computer and navigate the file system, however USB debugging is not enabled. I can use Kies 3 to create backup files (.spb and .sme) but Kies 3 does not offer the option of converting to .vcf etc. Kies 2 can normally convert the files, however Kies 2 can't open the files created by Kies 3.

How can I successfully export the contacts and SMS messages from the Galaxy S3 onto the new Google Nexus 6P?

Comment: Were you syncing through Google services? You really shouldn't have to back-up contacts nowadays.

Comment: Unfortunately not! All of the contacts were saved onto the phone.

Comment: In the future, sync your contacts though google. I think you might be out of luck with restoring the incompatible files.

Comment: Point taken, but obviously that doesn't help me now. I'm not so keen on giving up... i.e. being proficient in C# is there a spec on the file layout so that it can be read with some code etc?

Comment: You can always open it with notepad++ and see what you can figure out.